# Error signing Electron package using Code signing certificate

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, code-signing-certificate

We exported .exe and followed process as defined here https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide, after that I configured and used `electron-windows-store`  to export .appx and sign that.

We have purchased code signing certificate form Godaddy. I exported *pfx* s defined here https://au.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698?locale=en.

Check my request for exporting appx signing that below.

> > ```
> > electron-windows-store `  
> >   --input-directory D:\Arpit\GSWindows\LiveBuild\GSWDesktop `
> >   --output-directory D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Output `
> >   --package-version 1.0.0.0 `
> >   --windows-kit 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit' `
> >   --desktop-converter 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_8wekyb3d8bbwe' `
> >   --publisher 'CN=Ifcondition' `
> >   --package-name GoSession `
> >   --dev-cert 'D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Certificates\GSCertificate.pfx' `
> >   --cert-pass ##########
> > ```

Once `appx` is exported and it comes to signing the certificate, it gives an **Error:**

> The following certificate was selected:
>       Issued to: Ifcondition
>       Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
>       Expires:   ### ### ## ##:##:## ####
>       SHA1 hash: ###########################################
>
> Done Adding Additional Store
>
> Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b)
>
> SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
>
> Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe exited with code: 1
>       at ChildProcess.child.on (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-windows-store\lib\utils.js:74:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
>   Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe exited with code: 1
>       at ChildProcess.child.on (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-windows-store\lib\utils.js:74:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)

I also tried signing exported appx using SignTool with following request:

```
 .\SignTool sign /f "D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Certificates\GSCertificate.pfx" /p ########## SHA256 "D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Output\GoSession.appx"
```

Which also gives similar **Error**:

> Done Adding Additional Store
>   SignTool Error: File not found: SHA256
>   SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
>   Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146889723/0x80091005)

I have checked several reference document to understand the process and error but I couldn't figure the problem, here are some links which found useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-identity

Comment: Why you are adding the SHA256 without any command? To sign an app package that was created with the default SHA256 hash, you specify the /fd hashAlgorithm parameter as SHA256. Like `SignTool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f signingCert.pfx /p password filepath.appx`

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I tried that but it still gives error, check,   

`.\SignTool sign /fd SHA256 /a /f "D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Certificates\GSCertificate.pfx" /p aaaaaaaa "D:\Arpit\GSWindows\Output\GoSession.appx”`


`Done Adding Additional Store`  
`SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.`  
`Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b)`  
`PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit>`

Comment: As I can see in the electron's tutorial, it recommends to use DAC when converting the app, have you tried this?